# Identifying the origin of likes for a particular page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Hope this is in the right section(s). :)

**Context:** I have a site that has a central Like button (one that connects to the Facebook page for our organization), and each of our articles also has its own Like button (the button that's really more like a "share" button).

**Question:** Is it possible to see the origins of the individual likes on one of the articles? For the likes directly to the Facebook page, we can just go to the page and view the users who like it. But for the individual articles, the like count is generated completely differently (shares, "likes", the link being posted in PM's, etc.), and there appears to be no centralized "here's where this number is coming from" page. Is there any way to get an idea of where article likes are coming from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is covered on the [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

See **What is the best way to know which Like button on my page generated the traffic?**

You add a `ref` parameter to the like button, and the value of this will come back in the inbound clicks as the `fb_ref` parameter in the referring URL

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I'm wrong, but that doesn't appear to be exactly what I'm looking for. Looks like that helps you identify traffic to your site as a result of the link being shared. What I'm looking for is a way to look at all of the times that the link has been shared within Facebook (see who's sharing it and in what ways). Is this possible with what you've provided?